# How to populate a template string in CFML

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, cfml, lucee

Forgive the newbie question here, but I am trying to allow for custom variables in a string that I would pull from a query, and replace those with results of another query.  So to simplify it, I would need something like this...

```
<cfset mystring = "This is my %firstname% and this is my %lastname%.">
```

Then suppose I had query results of MyQuery,first and MyQuery.last, I would like the most efficient way to replace the %firstname% and %lastname% in mystring with the query results.

Any help/example would be so appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resolving variables inside a Coldfusion string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871249/resolving-variables-inside-a-coldfusion-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for replaceNoCase()?

```
<cfset myNewString = replaceNoCase(myString, '%firstname%', myQuery.first, 'all')>
<cfset myNewString = replaceNoCase(myNewString, '%lastname%', myQuery.last, 'all')>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Lucee then you can take advantage of `replace(string, struct)` (showing cfscript syntax):

```
template = "This is my %firstname% and this is my %lastname%.";

replaceMap = {
    "%firstname%" : "John"
   ,"%lastname%"  : "Doe"
}

populated = replace(template, replaceMap);    // use replaceNoCase() for case-insensitivity
```

All of the replacements take place in the Java code which is much more efficient than doing it in a CFML loop.

Also, `replace()` is  much more efficient than `replaceNoCase()`, so if the CaSe is known in advance you should use `replace()` where possible, or consider normalizing the case, e.g. with `lcase()`, prior to calling `replace()`.

Answer (score 1):

if you had a query like this:

```
<cfquery name="myquery" datasource="mydatasource">
  select firstname, lastname from users
</cfquery>
```

then you would out put the values from that by doing the following:

```
<cfoutput query="myquery">
   <cfset variables.mystring = "This is my #firstname# and this is my #lastname#.">
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Yes, I understand that...  I need to REPLACE the contents of a string where %firstname% and %lastname% are found

Comment: @mck Why? If you're querying to get this information anyway, you already have it inside of ColdFusion. ReplaceNoCase() will work, but it would be much more efficient to just use a ColdFusion variable in #s to output a variable. Unless your string is already fixed and you can't replace the %s with #s.

Comment: @shawn - This is a scenario in which we allow people to create templates for emails to go out, sh=o they need to be able to save something like:  Dear %firstname%,  -  And whenever we need to send out an email that uses that template, we need to do a query, pull up the values and their template, and send it out.

Comment: Its also useful for 'shortcode' functionality like in wordpress. Users can enter `%shortcode%` in cms text contents. Then later CFML can replace the shortcode with data.